# TCP 4-way close

Tags: tcp, handshake

I was under the impression that in order to close a TCP session a 4-way close/handshake need to happen. Looking at a TCP dump (from an F5 loadbalancer)

> 21:44:39.149332 IP 1.1.1.1.54934 > 2.2.2.2.https: Flags [**S**], seq 2406625584, win 29200, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1897921772 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0 out slot1/tmm1 lis=
>
> 21:44:39.163133 IP 2.2.2.2.https > 1.1.1.1.54934: Flags [**S.**], seq 4293133240, ack 2406625585, win 28960, options [mss 1418,sackOK,TS val 220337697 ecr 1897921772,nop,wscale 7], length 0 in slot1/tmm1 lis=
>
> 21:44:39.163277 IP 1.1.1.1.54934 > 2.2.2.2.https: Flags [**.**], ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1897921786 ecr 220337697], length 0 out slot1/tmm1 lis=

The TCP 3 way handshake to set up the connection look exactly as expected, with a SYN, SYN ACK and SYN. However the tear-down uses 3 message: FIN ACK, FIN ACK and ACK... I don't understand why this is different from what literature say. Is this the TCP implementation F5 uses? Do vendors use a different implementation of TCP?

> 21:44:39.163282 IP 1.1.1.1.54934 > 2.2.2.2.https: Flags [**F.**], seq 1, ack 1, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1897921786 ecr 220337697], length 0 out slot1/tmm1 lis=
>
> 21:44:39.176912 IP 2.2.2.2.https > 1.1.1.1.54934: Flags [**F.**], seq 1, ack 2, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 220337700 ecr 1897921786], length 0 in slot1/tmm1 lis=
>
> 21:44:39.177067 IP 1.1.1.1.54934 > 2.2.2.2.https: Flags [**.**], ack 2, win 229, options [nop,nop,TS val 1897921800 ecr 220337700], length 0 out slot1/tmm1 lis=

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I have looked over this with a colleague of mine and he had a possible answer as to why we see a double ACK.

We see the same ACK in the 3rd packet of the TCP 3-way SYN and in the first packet of the TCP 4-way close. According to my college, because there is no actual data send after the 3-way handshake, it will send another ACK to make sure the other host knows the session is terminated, because no data is flowing and so the other side doesn't see a stop of dataflow. So it sends another ACK to make sure.

So the actual TCP close is: 
-> FIN 
<- FIN, ACK 
-> ACK

Answer (score 2):

Notice how the other peers stack combines `FIN` with `ACK`.

The four-way hand-shake is really:

1. Local host sends `FIN` to remote host
2. Remote host sends `ACK` for the previous message
3. Remote host sends `FIN` to local host
4. Local host sends `ACK` to remote host

The remote peer combines the two middle steps into a single step as an optimization (to limit the number of packets sent).

Comment: That still doesn't explain what I'm seeing. Look closely. A dot is representing a ACK. So I see 3 ACK's... Please explain the final ACK. I'm seeing this: 1. FIN ACK 2. FIN ACK 3. ACK. Up until number 2, your story makes sense, but what about the last ACK...

Comment: @frankguthrie The first `ACK` is probably for the *previous` packet sent to you. So your host sends a `FIN` (to start the teardown) and an `ACK` for the previous packet. Then the remote host replies with its `ACK` *and* its own `FIN`, and lastly your host `ACK` the `FIN` it received. Combining `ACK` with another packet is not uncommon, quite the opposite,

Comment: Actually, I did not omitted anything from the output. We do monitoring on the TCP port, so no data is sent. After the TCP 3-way handshake (SYN, SYN ACK, ACK) the connection is immediately terminated, no data is sent. So why would the First ACK combined with the first FIN ACK something that is already ACK'ed??

Comment: @frankguthrie Okay that's a little different. You should probably edit your question to show the *complete* log then (since it will not be longer than what you already have) and elaborate a little on the issue (basically what you said in this comment).

Comment: The complete log show exactly the same, it's a repeat of the 2 blocks seen above. A TCP healthmonitor checks is the TCP port is listening on that port.